# Apt-get update and installed failed in ubuntu 13.10 in virtual machine

Tags: installation, apt-get, ubuntu-13.10

I have installed **VMplayer** in my Ubuntu 14.04 and in the VM I need to run Ubuntu 13.10.

I have installed 13.10 on my VM. But in 13.10 when I need to run `sudo apt-get update` it failed. And also I can't run any install from `apt-get`. Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue? These are Errors

```
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources                                
  404  Not Found
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
```

and when i try to install packages using `apt-get install` it gives this error.

```
sajith@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package git
```

Comment: When you tell us the error ....

Comment: Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources                                
  404  Not Found
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages this is the error.

Comment: fralan i have edited question.This is what i got.

Comment: Looks pretty much like an network issue for me. Please check networking of the virtual box

Comment: Do you have an internet connection? Most VMs will require changing the network settings of the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 13.10 is Saucy Salamander, but your output says "raring" (for Raring Ringtail) which is 13.04. Both 13.10 and 13.04 have reached end-of-life however, see: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases.

Discontinued (end of life) versions are removed from the main repositories, and that is why you get the errors. I would recommend that you upgrade to a supported version that receives security updates. If you cannot do that, then you can edit /etc/apt/sources.list to use [http://old-releases.ubuntu.com](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/) instead. I don't know if the "extras" repository is available though.